# click .toggle add/remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i click `#tool` I want to add the class `.spanner` to the div `#drill`.

However when `#drill` has the class `.spanner` and `#tool` is clicked i want the class to be removed?

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function:

```
$("#tool").click(function() {
    $("#drill").toggleClass("spanner");
});
```